# Spring boot Jersey with groovy/gradle fails on startup

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

We're just starting a new project, and are looking into spring-boot for kickstarting our development. spring-boot seems powerful, but there's some magic going on that we yet don't understand.

I've cloned the spring-boot samples and ran the Jersey Example. 
So far so good.

I then converted this to Groovy/Gradle.

relevant sections of the build script looks like this

```
.
.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
//        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.M2")
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'
    }
}
.
.
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
.
.
dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.13"
}
```

when running gradle bootRun the application fails to start

the exception is

```
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
        2014-10-29 09:38:01.982 ERROR 17977 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)

            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition owing to internal class not found. This c at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:146)
        an happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:177)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:146)
            at .
    .
    .
    .
        pplicationBuilder.java:143)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/serv at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder$run.call(Unknown Source)
        let/view/UrlBasedViewResolver
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at geit.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.groovy:28)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
..
.
.       org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:145)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
            at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:145)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:678)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeaat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireC                                                                                                                                                      mesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
        apableBeanFactory.java:678)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:373)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:165)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:153)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1394)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:122)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:96)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:373)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:165)
            ... 19 more
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:153)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:122)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:96)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            ... 19 common frames omitted
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            ... 50 more 
        2014-10-29 09:38:01.983  INFO 17977 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@76e68f                                                                                                                                                            59: startup date [Wed Oct 29 
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**To solve this ClassNotFoundException I add the following dependency
"org.springframework:spring-webmvc"**

when running gradle bootRun the application starts

However, this also triggers alot of extra setup that I really don't want

This is the log from the spring-boot-samples using Maven

```
2014-10-29 09:43:01.466  INFO 18089 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1414 ms
2014-10-29 09:43:01.612  INFO 18089 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'jerseyServlet' to [/*]
2014-10-29 09:43:01.614  INFO 18089 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2014-10-29 09:43:02.071  INFO 18089 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-10-29 09:43:02.081  INFO 18089 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2014-10-29 09:43:02.089  INFO 18089 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2014-10-29 09:43:02.096  INFO 18089 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool      : Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2014-10-29 09:43:02.109  INFO 18089 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2014-10-29 09:43:02.111  INFO 18089 --- [           main] sample.jersey.SampleJerseyApplication    : Started SampleJerseyApplication in 2.456 seconds (JVM running for 2.792)
```

This is the log from my gradle build, including the spring-webmvc dependency

```
2014-10-29 09:42:20.276  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-10-29 09:42:20.277  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5680 ms
2014-10-29 09:42:20.881  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'jerseyServlet' to [/*]
2014-10-29 09:42:20.883  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-10-29 09:42:20.884  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2014-10-29 09:42:20.885  INFO 18078 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.204  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.239  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.510  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.580  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-10-29 09:42:21.580  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-10-29 09:42:21.611  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.611  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.649  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3450feef: startup date [Wed Oct 29 09:42:14 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-10-29 09:42:22.064  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2014-10-29 09:42:22.115  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
2014-10-29 09:42:22.118  INFO 18078 --- [           main] geit.ApiApplication                      : Started ApiApplication in 8.126 seconds (JVM running for 9.259)
> 2014-10-29 09:42:51.012  INFO 18078 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3450feef: startup date [Wed Oct 29 09:42:14 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

As we can see, the following is now auto registered

Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]

and spring-webmvc is mapping urls

```
2014-10-29 09:42:21.510  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.580  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-10-29 09:42:21.580  INFO 18078 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2014-10-29 09:42:21.611  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2014-10-29 09:42:21.611  INFO 18078 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

I am not sure why I need to include the spring-webmvc dependency to actually start the server when using gradle, as opposed to using Maven?
I want to solve this before proceeding with spring-boot so that we don't run into springmvc/jersey conflicts later on
Is this a bug? 
As user error?

Any help appreciated
:)

**Application class**

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//class ApiApplication {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ApiApplication);
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        new ApiApplication()
                .configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApiApplication))
                .run(args);
//        SpringApplication.run ApiApplication, args
    }

}
```

**Simplified build script**

I have simplified the build script, no multimodule build, just spring-boot-jersey.
Rest of the code is from the samples. It still fails.

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
            maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    //        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    repositories {
    //    jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }


    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    //apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


    version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'


    jar {
        baseName = 'jersey-test'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey",
                "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.7"
        testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    }
```

**Dependencies from the simpliefied build***

```
~/Development/git-repos/geitkontroll/jersey-test (geit-32) $ gradle dependencies --configuration runtime
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey: -> 1.2.0.M2
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.0.M2
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.M2
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.0.M2
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.0.M2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.2.0.M2
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.7
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
|    |    |    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2
|    |    |         +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.7
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.13
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.0.M2
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.55
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.55
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.55
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.2.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.7
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.7
|    |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
|    |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.7
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.2.0
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.2.0
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.2.0
|    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
|    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.7
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.7 (*)
|    |    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.2.0
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.7
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.2.0
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.7 (*)
|    |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.7
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.7 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.7 (*)
|    |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
|    \--- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:2.7
|         +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.7 (*)
|         +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.7 (*)
|         +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2:2.2.0
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:config-types:2.2.0
|         |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:2.2.0
|         |    |         +--- org.glassfish.hk2:core:2.2.0
|         |    |         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    |         +--- org.jvnet:tiger-types:1.4
|         |    |         \--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:bean-validator:2.2.0
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:core:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-config:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-runlevel:2.2.0
|         |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.2.0 (*)
|         |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:class-model:2.2.0
|         |         \--- junit:junit:4.3.1
|         +--- org.glassfish.hk2:spring-bridge:2.2.0
|         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.1.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.3.RELEASE -> 4.1.1.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
\--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.7
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.7 (*)
     +--- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:2.7
     |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0
     +--- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.5.0
     |    +--- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.5.0
     |    |    \--- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:2.5.0
     |    \--- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:2.5.0
     \--- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:2.5.0

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Comment: Are u using @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: You shouldn't need a dependency on spring-webmvc: the Maven-based Jersey sample doesn't depend on it. I can build and run the sample using Gradle with dependencies on jersey-media-moxy and spring-boot-starter-jersey so I suspect it must be something that's being pulled in by your domain project that's triggered the problem. Can you update the question with the output from `./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime`?

Comment: Also, as the error recommends, have you checked that you're not component scanning Spring classes? For example because you've put @ComponentScan on a class in the default package.

Comment: Yes, using  @EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: I've updated with the Application class. This is not in the default package.

Comment: Unable to add update of dependencies task due to size limit. Are there other ways of sharing this info?

Comment: Please see updated question. I have updated/simplified the build. Still the same error. Using the same code as the samples

Comment: dependencies report added. Had to remove some of the stacktrace due to size limit

Comment: Ok, I have checked out the samples, copied the simplified build script to the root dir, and ran gradle compileJava then gradle bootRun. It still fails. @AndyWilkinson - I am not sure how you are able to run the samples with gradle. Can you test with the gradle script above?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have isolated the problem to the compile dependency "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.7". When including this dependency, the error occurs. I am not sure how to bypass this problem, as we are using standalone gorm and thus needs the different groovy modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found a [bug in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1793). Thanks for the help in tracking it down. As mentioned in the bug report you can work around the problem by excluding the auto-configuration for Groovy templates:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.class)
class ApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    // …
}
```