# Unable to set NamingStrategy using Spring Boot + GORM + Gradle

Tags: hibernate, gradle, grails-orm, spring-boot

We're starting a new project using Spring Boot with GORM and Gradle. I've been able to configure most properties for hibernate, but I have so far been unable to find the correct way to set the **naming strategy**.

### Attempts

I've tried setting a variety of properties in **application.properties** and adding the file **hibernate.properties**. We're using auto-configuration, and I see props are discovered and added in **HibernateGormAutoConfiguration**.

I've also made some attempts creating the entity manager and session factory beans with no luck.

**Examples from application.properties** (trying all permutations):

```
spring.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none # this works!!
# from now on none works
# I tried all permutations with combinations of
# *.hibernate[.ejb].* and *.naming_strategy/naming-strategy
spring.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.hibernate.ejb.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.properties.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.gorm.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.gorm.properties.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
gorm.hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

**Examples from src/main/resources/hibernate.properties:**

```
hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
hibernate.ejb.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

**Logging and stacktrace when starting application and trying to load entity:**

```
2014-11-03 10:12:04.381  INFO 81729 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from ... 
resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.ejb.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy, hibernate.namingStrategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}


2014-11-03 10:09:28.825  WARN 81619 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: 42S22
2014-11-03 10:09:28.825 ERROR 81619 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'origin_marking'.
2014-11-03 10:09:28.839 ERROR 81619 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[jerseyServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jerseyServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'origin_marking'.] with root cause
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'origin_marking'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
```

---

### Code examples

Unfortunately overriding field names on a per field basis is not a viable solution:

```
static mapping = {
    columns {
        originMarking column: 'originMarking'
    }
}
```

Excerpts from the build files look like this:

```
.. // main build file
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.M2")
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'
    }
}
..
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
..
.. // domain build file
jar.baseName = 'domain'
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE",
            "joda-time:joda-time:2.5",
            'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1',
            "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4",
            "net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.7"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
}
..
.. // api build file
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
jar.baseName = 'api'
dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey"
    ..
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

---

This code is part of the same project as the question asked here: [Spring boot Jersey with groovy/gradle fails on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626285/spring-boot-jersey-with-groovy-gradle-fails-on-startup)

Comment: Have you tried the documented `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy` in the `application.properties`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I was trying to say (somewhat cryptically) with 'trying all permutations' along with the comment on the end of application.properties '# as well as with hibernate.ejb* and *.naming_strategy/naming-strategy'. I changed that part of my description, hopefully it made it clearer.

Comment: Then I suspect that GORM is setting/overriding it internally or something like that.

Comment: I share your suspicion but have so far been unable to track down where the override (or something similiar) happens. Downgrading the spring-boot version is an alternative (to find out if this could be a bug in the current version), but because *-starter-jersey was new in the current version I was hoping to avoid doing this.

Comment: I suspect the gorm internals but my GORM knowledge is far to little for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails does use the `spring.hibernate.naming_strategy` setting, but not in such a way that it's then used as you'd expect, and it leaves the default naming strategy untouched. I'm not sure what the reasons for that are. You might want to [raise an issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS) to discuss it with the Grails team.

In the meantime, it's possible to configure the default naming strategy programatically by calling `configureNamingStrategy` on `AbstractGrailsDomainBinder`. For example:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.configureNamingStrategy('DEFAULT', DefaultNamingStrategy)
        SpringApplication.run Application, args
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked as a charm @AndyWilkinson, much obliged. I'll raise an issue with the Grails team.