# Entity Class name is transformed into SQL table name with underscores

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EmailTemplate")
public class EmailTemplate {
```

Despite the table annotation, I receive `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'email_template'`. How can I prevent an entity class such as EmailTemplate being transformed into email_template table name?

Edit:

I'm using Spring Boot: start JPA. From my build.gradle file,

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Spring by default uses `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy` which splits camel case names with underscore. Try setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy` in `application.properties`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711323/unable-to-set-namingstrategy-using-spring-boot-gorm-gradle) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for more info.

Comment: for hibernate v5: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: Can this be done with an annotation instead of a properties file?

Comment: How can we achieve that in application.yml file??

Comment: @SyedZeeshanAli: It should be same like you do for server port similarly this key value pair should be defined

Comment: @SyedZeeshanAli User below code. I confirmed it is working.
`
sping:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
`

Comment: this did not work for me

Answer (score 82):

For **hibernate v5**:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Answer (score 12):

For ***Spring Boot 2*** (checked with `2.2.6.RELEASE`) it should be configuration `yml` file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

So you could have model like:

```
@Table(name = "tblDepartments")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dpID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    @Column(name = "dpName", length = 25)
    private String name;
```

and populate tables at startup with `data.sql`:

```
INSERT INTO tblDepartments (dpName) VALUES ('Gryffindor');
INSERT INTO tblDepartments (dpName) VALUES ('Hufflepuff');
```

---

Also, found that for **PostgreSQL** additional step is needed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"tblEmployees\"")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "\"empID\"")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    @Column(name = "\"empName\"", length = 25)
    private String name;
```

Otherwise, the names at DB will be in lowercase, like `tblemployees`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this in your `appplication.properties.`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two most common `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy`s:

```
org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
# also deprecated in 2.6 in favor of CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
# for removal in 2.8
org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties` holds:

```java
private void applyNamingStrategies(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    applyNamingStrategy(properties, AvailableSettings.IMPLICIT_NAMING_STRATEGY, this.implicitStrategy,
            () -> SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    applyNamingStrategy(properties, AvailableSettings.PHYSICAL_NAMING_STRATEGY, this.physicalStrategy,
            () -> CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.class.getName());
}
```

so by default `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy` is in use and you have underscores...

Answer (score -2):

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];     
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Both are required :

```
implicit-strategy 
physical-strategy
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved.

Invalid Object Name: Springboot with JPA(SQL server)

In application.yaml/properties specify the

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy

jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none # Defaults to "none" when NOT in embedded mode
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl