# Is there a way to use properties with "And" in a spring data JPA query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In our project, we have an entity class `Employee`, that looks something like this:

```java
@Entity
class Employee {
  ...
  long travelDistanceAndTimeId;
  ...
}
```

We now want to use Spring Data JPA in order to find all employees that have a certain `travelDistanceAndTimeId`, so our EmployeeRepository looks like this:

```java
interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository<Employee, Long> {

  List<Employee> findByTravelDistanceAndTimeId(long travelDistanceAndTimeId);
}
```

However, this fails, since Spring Data JPA thinks this method should look for an employee that has a given `travelDistance` and a given `timeId`, because as per the [Spring Data JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details), the `and` is treated as a method predicate keyword here.

Is there a way to make Spring Data JPA treat the `travelDistanceAndTimeId` as one field, and disable the "AND" method keyword for this query?

Comment: What is your field `travelDistanceAndTimeId` ? How can you save the 'travelDistance' AND 'TimeId' in one Long field? I would expect 2 fields, `travelDistance` and `timeId`

Comment: @Willem irrelevant to the question though.

Comment: You can consider native query https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: annotate the field with the `@Column(name="TravelDistanceAndTimeId")` and have the java field named without the *and*  `long TravelDistanceTimeId;`  then name the method as `findByTravelDistanceTimeId`  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296713/spring-jpa-hibernate-findby-column-name-return-empty-collection

Comment: @Willem, you can think about this as a reference to a `TraveDistanceAndTime` entity, but my question is not specific to this one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Popeye said, consider using a native query as follows:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT <columns> FROM <TableName> WHERE travelDistanceAndTimeId=?1", nativeQuery = true)
public <returnType> findByTravelDistanceAndTimeId(long travelDistanceAndTimeId);
```

Comment: Hi, is there any restriction to use native? a jpql query would also work I suppose e.g. `"SELECT e FROM  Employee e WHERE e.travelDistanceAndTimeId=?1"`