# How to prevent Spring Boot/Hibernate from converting entity column names from PascalCase to snake_case?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, entity

I stumbled upon a strange error today. One of my Java Persistence Application programming interface (JPA) entities in Spring Boot application is not working. I tracked the problem down to a single column:

```java
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "NameWrittenInPascalCase")
java.lang.String c;
```

When I checked the Structured Query Language (SQL) query which Spring Boot/Hibernate generates I discovered the problem. It seams that Spring Boot or Hibernate converts the `NameWrittenInPascalCase` into `name_written_in_pascal_case` (just written in snake case). (In database, of course, my column name is written in PascalCase).

For gods sake, why?

And how to prevent it from doing so?

If you need aditional info, I use Spring Boot version 2.5.7.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the string with backticks? Like `@javax.persistence.Column(name = "\`NameWrittenInPascalCase\`")`

Comment: No, but it does not help. In query sent to server there is still `name_written_in_pascal_case`. :(

Comment: depending upon ur hibernate version the property name needs to be adjusted in application.properties. refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087626/entity-class-name-is-transformed-into-sql-table-name-with-underscores

Comment: Oh, thank you. It looks like this question is possible duplicate of the question which you linked. I did not find it when i searched for it before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your project `application.properties` file set the naming strategy:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Default value is `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy`

***UPDATE:***

If previous property does not solved your problem, you can use this one (For newer versions of **Hibernate**):

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Unfortunately, hibernate still sends `name_written_in_pascal_case` instead of `NameWrittenInPascalCase` even after setting this property.

Comment: Try this property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` @KRISTIJANTOMASINI

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much.
Can you please update your answer so that i can accept it and give you reputation?