# JPA Entity @Table(name) Annotation Not Generating Correct Table Name

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I'm facing an issue while working with JPA entities in my Spring Boot application. I have an entity class named DriverMaster with the @Entity and @Table(name = "driverMaster") annotations to specify the desired table name. However, when the table is created in the database, it's being named as driver_master instead of driverMaster.

Here's my DriverMaster entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driverMaster")
@Data
public class DriverMaster {
     // Attributes and getters/setters
}
```

I have used these properties

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
```

but nothing works!!!

Comment: Try with either lower case or upper case only ad table name

Comment: But i need to use driverMaster only, cant make it uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087626/entity-class-name-is-transformed-into-sql-table-name-with-underscores) might help.

Comment: Have you checked the db dialect? It affects the way Hibernate generates SQL statements so maybe the table names too

Comment: I'm using  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Class name is transformed into SQL table name with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087626/entity-class-name-is-transformed-into-sql-table-name-with-underscores)

Comment: Hi @Dimitris it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @sandeepkande what did you do and did not work?

As described spring splits camel case convention to underscore convention depending in the hibernate version

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy`

or

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`


Should fix it

Comment: What database do you use and version? Also what spring boot version do you use?

Comment: I see that you use lombok, remove the data annotation it might also be the root of issues you can use 'Getter' and 'Setter' but overriding the equals on entity might cause issues

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the properties being picked up by Spring/Hibernate? I'd make sure this properties file actually affects your JPA context. Check you don't have something else defined in a persistence.xml or persistence property you are passing in via code. Otherwise, PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl should be the only one you need to set. See https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-field-naming-spring-boot for details

Comment: @Chris , I have checked with all the above mentioned properties one by one and PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl giving tables with all small case, checked twice with same property.

Comment: @Dimitris , working with java 1.8 , SpringBoot 2.7.14, MySQL 8.0.30, and Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0)
Build id: 20230309-1520

Comment: @sandeepkande did you try to remove the Data annotation?