# SpringBoot not able to find MySQL table while querying all records

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have `SpringBoot-MySQL` application where I am using a `controller` to query all the records from a table and display it on a `Thymeleaf` page. But the error says that it is not able to find the table. I checked the table name and it indeed is `CF_JOB_CONTROLLER`. Not sure how it is lowering the case of tablename and appending the schema name in front of it.

**Error**

```
2018-07-10 17:24:36.487  INFO 13244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 165 ms
2018-07-10 17:24:37.926  INFO 13244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2018-07-10 17:24:38.510  WARN 13244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2018-07-10 17:24:38.511 ERROR 13244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'elog.cf_job_controller' doesn't exist
2018-07-10 17:24:38.641 ERROR 13244 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'elog.cf_job_controller' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:307) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.synapsegroup.jobmanager.controller.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final String appName = "ThymeleafTour";

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Guest") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("title", appName);

        //get all jobs
        List<Job> jobs = jobRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("jobs:" + jobs);
        model.addAttribute("jobSize", jobs.size());

        return "home";
    }

}
```

**JobRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Long> {

}
```

**Job.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CF_JOB_CONTROLLER")
@Data
public class Job implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "JOB_CONTROLLER_ID")
    private Integer jobControllerId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "JOB_NAME")
    private String jobName;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For naming issue :**

Spring by default uses `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.SpringNamingStrategy` because of which camel case names are split with an underscore.

For Hibernate 5+, you need to set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

in `application.properties` if you want table name to same as you specify in your POJO.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711323/unable-to-set-namingstrategy-using-spring-boot-gorm-gradle#answer-26715960) answer has Groovy implementation, which you can try in java.