# @Table(name="camelCase") changes to snake_case:"camel_case"

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class as follows:

```
@Entity(name = "companyCode")
@Table(name = "companyCode")
public class CompanyCode {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "companyCode")
    String cCode;
}
```

Instead of creating the table name as companyCode in sql it creates the table as "company_code". The column name is also created as "company_code".

Table in mysql:
[image]

Is there any way to create the table and column using camelCase instead of snake case?

Java Version: 11

Spring Boot version: 2.7.0

Spring Data JPA Version: Latest

Answer (score 2):

FOUND THE ANSWER.
Set naming strategy in hibernate in application property as

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

link for reference:
[Unable to set NamingStrategy using Spring Boot + GORM + Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711323/unable-to-set-namingstrategy-using-spring-boot-gorm-gradle)